# When importing tensorflow, I get the following error: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, anaconda

I have installed Ancaconda3 and Tensorflow. When I try to import Tensorflow in python shell I receive the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 980, in _find_and_load SystemError:
> <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with
> an error set ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to
> import ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

I am not sure what the problem is as numpy is installed on my system and can be successfully imported in python.
I am using Windows10.

Comment: [Some peope](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11871) say that upgrading fixed the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem with Python 3.9 and numpy 1.23.2. After upgrading Python to 3.10.5 it worked for me.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I also had the same issue.
It got resloved once I upgraded the numpy from 1.15.4 to 1.16.1.

If you're using pip:
`pip install numpy --upgrade`

Numpy that came with Anaconda3 is of version 1.15.4. so i upgraded and it worked.

---

Side note: if you're also using **scikit-image** in your script, be aware that numpy 1.16.3 has a conflict with old versions of scikit-image (e.g. you may get `ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_lengths'`). In that case, `pip install --upgrade scikit-image` from terminal solved the issue for me.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.19.0, still the same issue!

Comment: if still persists due to an already downloaded numpy, clear pip cache with `pip cache purge`

Answer (score 5):

Kindly check whether you have installed the numpy package from pip. Because if you are running on conda evironment, then all packages need to be downloaded from there.
Please use the below mentioned statement for this purpose

conda install -c anaconda numpy

Also make sure that the numpy version supports the Python version you are using.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue with python 3.8.9 and Numpy 1.24.1.

Downgrading to Numpy 1.21.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: the pyinstaller worked but when I execute the exe file, it does not work.

Comment: THANK YOU! After hitting this issue and finding advice elsewhere to roll back to older numpy (1.16) wasn't working, installing the specific numpy version you mentioned (1.21.0) solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two options in python 3.6

1. Install

> py pip -m install numpy==1.14.5

2. Upgrade

> py pip install numpy --upgrade

Note: the version most recently is 1.14.5

Answer (score 3):

For some other people looking for an easier fix, I just simply uninstalled `numpy` and reinstalled it again.