# when I installed tensorflow I get the following error ImportError: cannot import name '_set_madvise_hugepage' from 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I tried to install tensorflow on anaconda powershell propmt with the following steps

```
conda activate tensorflow
```

then

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==2.2.0
```

and finally

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

after that, it seems that tensorflow is installed but on a jupyter notebook when it tried to run

```
import numpy as np
```

and i got the following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     14 
     15 if missing_dependencies:
---> 16     raise ImportError(
     17         "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
     18     )

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\device name\anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: cannot import name '_set_madvise_hugepage' from 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' (C:\Users\device name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp38-win_amd64.pyd)
```

and the same thing happend when i tried to import pandas and even tensorflow

so how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try again after upgrading your Numpy version.
Attaching relevant threads for reference.
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665842/when-importing-tensorflow-i-get-the-following-error-no-module-named-numpy-cor),[link2](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12977)