# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a simple python program which I am running on a Mac machine.

```
import numpy as np


def main():
    print("np arr test")
    arr = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
    print(arr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've verified that the numpy library was correct installed through pip

```
pip3 list | grep numpy
msgpack-numpy                      0.4.4.3
numpy                              1.16.2
numpydoc                           0.8.0
```

I get the following error when I run the program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Python-numpy/Python-numpy-1.x.140450.0/AL2012/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Volumes/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Python-numpy/Python-numpy-1.x.140450.0/AL2012/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Volumes/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Python-numpy/Python-numpy-1.x.140450.0/AL2012/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/workplace/RPAsosDevelopmentWS/src/RPAsosDevelopmentPy/src/rp_asos_development_py/adhoc_dev/float_nan_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Volumes/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Python-numpy/Python-numpy-1.x.140450.0/AL2012/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Volumes/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Python-numpy/Python-numpy-1.x.140450.0/AL2012/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.6 from "/usr/local/bin/python3.6"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.18.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can you please help me figure out what I am missing? Appreciate your response!

NOTE : Based on the [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665842/when-importing-tensorflow-i-get-the-following-error-no-module-named-numpy-cor) I updated the numpy through the following command

pip3 install numpy --upgrade

```
pip3 list | grep numpy
    msgpack-numpy                      0.4.4.3
    numpy                              1.21.2
    numpydoc                           0.8.0
    WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.1; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
```

However I still see the error message