# Numpy in VS Code Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am new to Ubuntu and is trying to get Numpy working on VS Code. Following is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,5,7,9]
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("My X values")
plt.ylabel("My Y values")
plt.plot(x,y, 'b-^', lineWidth = 3, markersize = 7, label = "Blue Line")
plt.legend(loc = "upper center")
plt.show()
```

But the debugger gives me the following error:

```
No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Does anyone knows how to install that module? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665842/when-importing-tensorflow-i-get-the-following-error-no-module-named-numpy-cor

Comment: I have the latest version (1.21.2) but it still doesn't work