# Unable to Install numpy. No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is the complete error message I received:

```
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "D:\hugging-face\nlp\Scripts\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I checked my Python version by typing `python -v` it the output was 3.10.5 is that alright?

I tried checking the NumPy version by typing:

```
import numpy
numpy.version
```

However, it gave me the same error about numpy.core.multiarray_umatch`. So, I tried to install numpy by running the following command:

```
pip install numpy
```

It gave me the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (D:\python\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I would also like to add that there are two directories inside `lib` with names `numpy` and `numpy-1.21.5.dist-info`. So, I guess the library is already installed but I can;t use it for some reason.

The contents of my `pyvenv.cgf` file are:

```
home = D:\python
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.7.4
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665842/when-importing-tensorflow-i-get-the-following-error-no-module-named-numpy-cor

Comment: Thanks @Deepan I get the last error I mentioned while upgrading as well. :)

Comment: As I can see you are using virtualenv can you delete the virtualenv and try creating new virtual env

Comment: @Deepan Do I simply delete the `pyvenv.cfg` file?

Comment: "D:\hugging-face\nlp\Scripts\python.exe" in here `nlp` is the virtualenv folder and can you share the pyvenv.cfg content here

Comment: Why not try pip3?

Comment: It looks like for `Mapping` the module is changed from `collections` to `collections.abc`

Comment: Maybe it's because the python version is uncompatible with the numpy version. Try to use pip3 install it again.

Comment: @yupe How is `pip` different than `pip3`?

Comment: @Deepan So, what should I do to resolve the error?

Comment: Do you have anaconda?

Comment: @Deepan Yes, I installed it some tie ago but I don't have much experience with it.

Comment: then create new conda environment using `conda create -n <env-name> python>=3.10 numpy>=1.23` and activate the conda env using `conda activate <env-name>`

Answer (score 1):

This may work, just give it a try

as you are using python 3.10 you need to install numpy version greater than 1.21.5

create new environment

```
cd <path where you need your virtualenv>
python -m venv .venv
```

as you are using windows activate using virtual env
`.venv\Scripts\activate` assuming your are already in the virtualenv folder

then try `pip install numpy>=1.23`