# No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: c++, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use matploitlib_cpp on Windows 11 with Numpy 1.24.2 and Python 3.11, but I keep running in to the following error.

> Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

I know this has been posted at a million different places on the internet and I have tried following all the guides that says reinstalling numpy and whatever, it does not work for me. What I can see in my path ..\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core is that I have a file named _multiarray_umath.cp311-win_amd64.pyd but no file named _multiarray_umath. I also tried to use a virtual environement from Anaconda but I am not sure how to build matploitlib_cpp against such virtual enviornment.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665842/when-importing-tensorflow-i-get-the-following-error-no-module-named-numpy-cor?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C203.9465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using the release binaries instead of debug binaries.