# Embed python code in C++ using cpython: cannot import numpy

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cmake, cpython

I'm developing a C++ application (using CMake) that embeds a Python script. The application is responsible for initializing the data, passing it to the Python script, and retrieving the result.
However, when I execute the application, I encounter the following runtime error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`

I'm using the CPython library with Python version 3.10 and Numpy version 1.25.0. I have already attempted to update Numpy, but the issue persists.

Additionally, I have also tried using pybind11, but I encountered another problem with importing the Numpy library.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

- Edit 1:

This is the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(PYTHON_DIR ${PYTHON_DIRECTORY})

find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter NumPy Development REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PYTHON_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${PYTHON_DIR}/libs)

add_executable(cpython "main.cpp" "main.h" "pyhelper.h")

target_link_libraries(cpython PUBLIC Python3::NumPy)
```

In the CMakePresets.json file, I have specified the PYTHON_DIRECTORY.

Comment: This question may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665842/when-importing-tensorflow-i-get-the-following-error-no-module-named-numpy-cor. In particular, have you tried downgrading numpy? Uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've solved the problem, but I encountered the same issue a few days ago. The problem originates from CPython not being able to find the DLL it depends on. This issue might occur during the initialization process of CPython, but I haven't found a solution at the C++ level for handling this problem. However, you can try to resolve this problem by adding the directory where the DLL file is located to the Python environment, see if it will help.

**These DLL files are located in the "Library\bin" directory under the Python executable folder. For Python versions 3.8 and above, you can try the following code**:

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(PYTHON_HOME + r'\Library\bin')
```

**For Python versions < 3.8, you can try the following code**

```
import sys
sys.path.append(PYTHON_HOME + r'\Library\bin')
```

PYTHON_HOME is where your Python executable file locates. This code adds the DLL directory to the search path, allowing CPython to find the necessary DLL files.

I'm using an interactive embed Python, so I placed this code after Py_InitializeFromConfig and before Py_RunMain, using PyRun_SimpleString to execute it.

*Reference: https://www.cnblogs.com/liniganma/p/17668411.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter NumPy Development REQUIRED)
...
link_libraries(Python3::NumPy)
```

To your `CMakeLists.txt` file. For me it works fine with a similar environment (using CPython directly).
If that doesn't help, please post the exact lines of your `CMakeLists.txt` involving Python, and the import statements of your Python script.

Comment: I have tried to put these in CMake, but I am facing the same error. I have updated the question with the CmakeList.txt file.

Comment: Maybe the Python which runs in CPython is different then the one running in your the interpreter you're using to edit your script? Try import a script which simply prints the environment of python (without numpy) and running it twice - using CPython and directly. See if there's any difference.. For example:
`import sys;  print(sys.path); print(sys.executable)`
See if the paths are different. Also, try running (directly) `print(os.path.dirname(np.__file__))` and see if the path of numpy is different.. If numpy is not in `${PYTHON_DIR}`, try adding it to ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}`.